# how to get a function from a c# with envdte in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, envdte

I want to find a function in a c# file and make some changes in the body with powershell. I've read this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.codemodel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The below code find a c# file and return a CodeElement object and inside it you can manipulate the function body, params, attributes, etc.

```
    #Find the file
    function global:GetFile { param($Project,[string]$Path)
    $result = $false
    $directories = $Path -split '\\'
    if($directories[0]) {
        for($i=0;$i -lt $directories.count;$i++) {
            if(($Project).ProjectItems) {
                $Project = ($Project).ProjectItems | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $directories[$i]}       
            }   
        }
        if(!$Project) 
        { write-host "File not found"  }
        else  
        {  $result =  $Project   }
    }
    return $result
    }
    #Find the function
    function global:GetFunctionAsCM {
        param([object] $Project,[string] $Path,[string] $rootnamespaceSpace,[string]$partialFileName=$null)

        $file = GetFile -Project $Project -Path $Path

        $namespaceParts = $rootnamespaceSpace.Split(".")
        $codeModel = $file.ContainingProject.CodeModel
        $rootnamespace = $namespaceParts[0]

        for($i = 0; $i -lt $namespaceParts.Length;$i++) {           
            if ($codeModel.Kind -eq $null) {
                $codeModel = $CodeModel.CodeElements | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq $rootnamespace}
            } elseif ($codeModel.Kind -eq [EnvDTE.vsCMElement]::vsCMElementNamespace) {
                $codeModel = $CodeModel.Members | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq $rootnamespace}
            } elseif ($codeModel.Kind -eq [EnvDTE.vsCMElement]::vsCMElementClass) {
                if($partialFileName -ne $null -and $codeModel.Parts.length>1) { 
                    $codeModel = $codeModel.Parts | Where-Object {$_.ProjectItem.Name -eq $partialFileName}
                }
                $codeModel = $codeModel.Children | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq $rootnamespace}   
            }
            $rootnamespace  = "$rootnamespace." + $namespaceParts[$i+1]
        }   
        return $codeModel
    }
```